# Upper half of UISegmentControl not responding to touch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I m using UISegmentControl in my app
style - `UISegmentedControlStyleBordered`
used method to control event - `UIControlEventValueChanged`
But i found that upper half of each segment is not responding to touch.

I override `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` just to figure out whats going on but this method is not getting called for upper half of segment touch.

I checked default `iOS` app like reminder and `ios5` maps app which hav segment controls. But i found even those segment are not responding to touch in upper half. But segments in calendar app responds to upper half touch.

How to make whole segment responding to touch events ?

Comment: Could other views be overlapping or is the UISegmentControl's containing view smaller than it? Try setting the parent view `clipsSubviews = YES` and/or using the simulators `Debug->Color Blended Layers`

Comment: check its subview frame...

Comment: Its parent view is UIToolbar and has no property clipsSubview. And subview frames are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check its frame.If frame not set, then set the frame for UISegmentedControl,may be this will solve your problem.

Comment: Frames are set properly still issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in a UIToolbar, try setting the style to `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` instead of `UISegmentedControlStyleBordered` which is for a larger segmented control option.